# Fantasy book with red haired girl who burned her hair in fire to make it shorter to disguise herself

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read this book like about 10 years ago and I'm certain it starts with "Lord".

It's surely not "Lord of the Rings" because I clearly remembered I didn't want to read it.

The female protagonist in the book probably has red hair and at one point when trying to escape from the enemies and to looks less recognisable, she burned her hair in fire to make it shorter.

At the end of the book, the male love interest held on the ends of the female character's sleeves very hard and the FMC said smth like "it seemed as if he was trying to make sure I wouldn't leave him again" or something along those lines. Basically to ensure her staying with him. It's a pretty vague description but I hope someone knows what I'm talking about. I cannot even remember the plot but I just remember than I really enjoyed it and would like to re-read it.

Comment: Welcome to SF&F Stack Exchange!  Please be sure to take the [tour] and read over the [FAQ].  You might also want to look over "[ask]" -- your question needs some grammar, formatting, and punctuation improvements to be clear and easy to read for people trying to help you by identifying the book.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! Can you edit your question to indicate what  about the book makes it **fantasy**?

Comment: Did the fire she burned her hair in talk (i.e. was it inhabited by a flame demon)?